# Android view binding between modules

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, module, dependencies

Does view binding work between modules?

> How to reproduce: Create 2 modules >>> create layout1 in module1 and create layout2 in module2 >>> Create Fragment1 in module1 with view which will be including layout1, layout2 >>> try to get binding >>> layout1 will work becouse it is in the same module as Fragment1, but layout2 will not work becouse of wrong binding generation

My example:

**Authentication** module has dependency to **common** module.

**base_button.xml** is in **common** module.

**login_input_component.xml** is in **Authentication** module so there is no problem.

But this error occures on **loginButton** binding.

It tries to find BaseButtonBinding in authentication module even if base_button.xml is in another module.

[image]

All modules has:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Comment: I have't tried to reproduce your case, but I have project where binding class from module1 is used in module2 and it works. Have you checked your module gradle file?

Comment: Yeap everything is as it should be. Could you show me somehow your soulution?

Comment: @Nikron I have the same problem, ¿did you find a solution?

Comment: @PabloA.Martínez unfortunately not

Comment: Facing the same issue in a multi-module project. Did any one solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Surprisingly, the IDE can autocomplete/resolve the binding (using the example above `BasButtonBinding`) without errors but accessing it via `LoginInputComponentBinding` results in the mentioned error.

Comment: @Nikron I have tried the same, I'm getting the right files generated, can you make sure your IDE and Gradle are updated and you have `implementation project(":Module2")` in your module1 dependencies? can you share any github link with the same reproduction setup?

Comment: That is pretty old. I will try to reproduce it soon and post here something.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct you have this kind of structure

project
|   -- app
|   -- module1 [ contains layout_one.xml and layout_fragment.xml]
|   -- module2 [ contains layout_two.xml]

`layout_fragment.xml` will include both `layout_one.xml` and `layout_two.xml`

Now in order to make this work, all you need to do is go to **module1** `build.gradle` file and add this dependency

```
implementation project(":module2")
```

Note your app will be aware of module1 and module2 files but module1 and module2 files will not be aware of both of there existence. So by specifying this dependency we make **module1** to depend on **module2**

and also make sure in each module **viewBinding** is enabled

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as I said in my example module1 == Authentication, module2 == common, and the dependency is same as in your example. ViewBinding is enabled in all modules. If you want to get layout_two by binding it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.
Today, after a week I worked again on this issue and I had to *invalidate cache and restart* in Android Studio because `ViewBinding` classes were always highlighted red with "Can't resolve" but building and running was successful.
I did a *clean build* before and then *invalidate cache and restart*.

After that everything worked as aspected.

I hope this helps in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that Windows 10 restricted the download function in Android Studio and did not allow it to download. Maybe you should go through the process of building an Android Studio trust in Windows 10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).